# vue running function in child component from parent component

Tags: vue.js

I've got parent component with a button

```
<btn @click="validate">Run child method - and validate something!</btn>
<child-component></child-component>
```

And I have a child component which has a method:

```
methods:{
   validate () {...}
}
```

I want to call this method from my parent component. How to do that?

Are there any pros/cons on given solution?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Call a Vue JS component method from outside the component](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33682651/call-a-vue-js-component-method-from-outside-the-component)

Comment: @icecream_hobbit oh, that's right, but my question is much more simpler :)

Comment: I would recommend passing a bus to the child as a prop, so the child can call its own methods.
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43256978/event-from-parent-to-child-component/43258428#43258428

Comment: @RoyJ Thanks for this suggestion. I'll look at this

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can add the attribute ref and use the ref value to access the component/call its methods.

```
<child-component ref="child" ></child-component>


this.$refs.child.validate();
```

https://v2.vuejs.org/v2/guide/components.html#Child-Component-Refs

> Despite the existence of props and events, sometimes you might still
> need to directly access a child component in JavaScript. To achieve
> this you have to assign a reference ID to the child component using
> ref. For example:
>
> var parent = new Vue({ el: '#parent' }) // access child component
> instance var child = parent.$refs.profile

In your case: `<btn @click="$refs.child.validate()">Run child method - and validate something!</btn>`