# calling grandparent method from inside the grandchild component

Tags: javascript, vue.js, vuejs3

i have 3 nested components

```
<GrandParent />
   <Parent />
       <Child />
```

i have a button in my `Child` component and on double click i would like to call a function in `GrandParent` component

```
 <button @dblclick="this.$parent.callGrandParentFunction(model)"> call grandparent </button>
```

using `this.$parent` i can only access `Parent` methods ... is there any way to go one level higher and call a `GrandParent` method ?

there is a similar question on SO but it's about vue2

[VueJS Grandchild component call function in Great grandparent component](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43254812)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try to use provide/inject pattern :

GrandParent :

```js
export default {
  methods: {
      someMethod(){
       //
      }
  },
  provide() {
    // use function syntax so that we can access `this`
    return {
      someMethod: this.someMethod
    }
  }
}
```

in GrandChild component :

```js
export default {
  inject: ['someMethod'],
  created() {
    //run the method 
    this.someMethod()
  }
}
```